# Problema #17 layout_height

Tags: android, android-layout, menú, android-listview

Este error ya lo busque y todas las soluciones no me funcionan, no entiendo cual es el problema: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Resumo, tengo una clase BaseActivity donde tengo un toolbar y genero el código de un menu con "onCreateOptionsMenu". El toolbar es para todas las actividades, por eso en mi BaseActivity inicio mi toolbar (pero dependiendo de un parametro de la clase hija) ¿Por que?, por que el toolbar lo incluyo en las vistas ... y donde tengo una lista expandible, lo inclui en el archivo "header" y no lo inicio en BaseActivity sino en la actividad hija en si después de listViewMyCoursesBlocks.addHeaderView(header);

En fin en esta actividad de la lista expandible, al tocar el menu me tira el error y no tengo idea como solucionarlo.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_saval"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MyCoursesActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FrontActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name=".MyBlocksActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MyClassActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize"/>
</application>
```

**BaseActivity**

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity

{

protected SessionManager sesion;

```
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int layoutId, boolean initToolbar)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layoutId);

    if( initToolbar ){
        initToolBar();
    }

    sesion = SessionManager.getInstance(this);
    //if user is not in sesion, will redirect to frontactivity
    if(!sesion.sesion())
    {
        finish();
    }
}
public void initToolBar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.appbar_back);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.appbar_menu, null));
    if( getSupportActionBar() != null ) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menulateral, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.cerrarsesion:
            sesion.logout();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if( this.getLocalClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("MyCoursesActivity") )
    {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_saval)
            .setTitle("Salir")
            .setMessage("¿Está seguro que desea cerrar su sesión?")
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    sesion.clearSession();
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // user doesn't want to logout
                }
            })
            .show();
            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSavalBlue));
            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSavalBlue));
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

protected Map<String, String> checkParams(Map<String, String> map){
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();
        if(pairs.getValue()==null){
            map.put(pairs.getKey(), "");
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

Mi segunda actividad la cual genera el problema en algún punto:

**MyBlocksActivity**

public class MyBlocksActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    private ExpandableListView listViewMyCoursesBlocks;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private Course myCourse;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.activity_my_blocks, false);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    myCourse = i.getExtras().getParcelable("myCourse");

    listViewMyCoursesBlocks = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMyCoursesBlocks);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listexpandable_header, null);
    listViewMyCoursesBlocks.addHeaderView(header);
    //en super.Oncreate pasamos parametro falso ... para indicar si se carga el toolbar en BaseActivity
    //o en la actual
    initToolBar();

    if( !myCourse.getBannerUrl().isEmpty() && myCourse.getBannerUrl() != null )
    {
        ImageView bannerImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bannerImg);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(myCourse.getBannerUrl()).into(bannerImg);
    }

    //InitData
    initData(new VolleyCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(HashMap<String,List<Activity>> lHash, List<String> lDataHeader)
        {
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),lDataHeader,lHash);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            if( listAdapter.getGroupCount() == 1 ){
                listViewMyCoursesBlocks.expandGroup(0);
            }
        }
    });

    listViewMyCoursesBlocks.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            Activity myActivity = (Activity)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            if( myActivity.getIsBlocked() == 0 )
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClassActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("myActivity", myActivity);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            return  false;
        };
    });
}
public void initData(final VolleyCallback callback)
{
    final List<String> listDataHeader  = new ArrayList<>();
    final HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHash = new HashMap<>();

    final String url   = Globals.APIACTIVIDADES_URL;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject JSONresponse = new JSONObject(response);
                if ( !JSONresponse.has("error") )
                {
                    int actividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesActividadesArr_length = 0;
                    int bloquesArr_length = 0;

                    String bannerUrl = JSONresponse.getString("banner");
                    String bloque_nombre = "";

                    if ( JSONresponse.has("actividades") && JSONresponse.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray actividadesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("actividades");
                        actividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                        bloque_nombre = "BLOQUE I";
                        listDataHeader.add(bloque_nombre);

                        List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < actividadesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(i));
                            Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                            String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                            String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                            String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                            Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                            Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                            Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");
                            String blockName = bloque_nombre;

                            actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo, bannerUrl, blockName));
                        }
                        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),actividades);
                    }
                    if ( JSONresponse.has("bloques") && JSONresponse.get("bloques") instanceof JSONArray )
                    {
                        JSONArray bloquesArr = JSONresponse.getJSONArray("bloques");
                        bloquesArr_length = bloquesArr.length();

                        int ini = 0;
                        if( actividadesArr_length > 0 ){
                            ini = 1;
                        }

                        int romanNumber = 1;
                        for (int i = ini; i < bloquesArr_length; i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject bloque = new JSONObject(bloquesArr.getString(i));
                            String titulo_bloque  = bloque.getString("titulo");

                            bloque_nombre = "BLOQUE " + RomanNumerals.toRoman(romanNumber) + ": " + titulo_bloque;
                            listDataHeader.add(bloque_nombre);

                            List<Activity> actividades = new ArrayList<>();

                            if (bloque.has("actividades") && bloque.get("actividades") instanceof JSONArray)
                            {
                                JSONArray actividadesArr = bloque.getJSONArray("actividades");
                                bloquesActividadesArr_length = actividadesArr.length();

                                for (int j = 0; j < bloquesActividadesArr_length; j++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject activity = new JSONObject(actividadesArr.getString(j));

                                    Integer id   = activity.getInt("id");
                                    String title = activity.getString("titulo");
                                    String titlePref = activity.getString("tituloprefijo");
                                    String teacher = activity.getString("expositores");
                                    Integer isAccomplished = activity.getInt("cumplida");
                                    Integer isBlocked = activity.getInt("bloqueo");
                                    Integer hvVideo = activity.getInt("tienevideo");
                                    String blockName = bloque_nombre;

                                    actividades.add(new Activity(id, titlePref, title, teacher, isAccomplished, isBlocked, hvVideo, bannerUrl, blockName));
                                } //for actividades
                            }
                            romanNumber++;
                            listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(i),actividades);
                        } // for bloques
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONObject error = JSONresponse.getJSONObject("error");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: [" + error.getString("num") + "] " + error.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al recuperar sus datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            callback.onResponse(listHash, listDataHeader);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            String message = "Error de conexión";
            if( error.getMessage() != null && !error.getMessage().isEmpty() )
            {
                message += ": [" + error.getMessage() + "]";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<String, String> user = sesion.getUserDetails();

            // get user data from session
            params.put("sesion", user.get(sesion.getKEY_CODE()));
            params.put("curso", myCourse.getId().toString());
            return checkParams(params);
        }
    };
    queue.add(req);
}

private static class VolleyCallback
{
    void onResponse(HashMap<String,List<Activity>> listHash, List<String> listDataHeader) {

    }
}
```

}

**activity_my_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMyCoursesBlocks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

En esta parte en MyBlocksActivity inflo mi vista "header" y luego inicio toolbar.

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listexpandable_header, null);
    listViewMyCoursesBlocks.addHeaderView(header);
    //en super.Oncreate pasamos parametro falso ... para indicar si se carga el toolbar en BaseActivity
    //o en la actual
    initToolBar();
```

**listexpandable_header.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/includetoolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/includetoolbar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/myblocksheader"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSavalBlue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bannerImg"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="top">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="58dp"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:theme="@style/Toolbar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/appbar_logo"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Disculpen si se lleno mucho de archivos, tampoco se por que a veces el código se corta en el editor, pero se entiende yo creo.

Alguna ayuda ?, este es el error que me arroja.

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
                                                                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5824)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5992)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:480)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:803)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Solo por si acaso, en styles.xml tengo

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</style>
```

Se supone que debo enchular mas el toolbar, por lo cual le agregue un style por ahora en blanco. Y en AppTheme, no necesite cambiar nada, pero como se llama en el manifest, lo deje.

Se los agradecería por que llevo muchas horas en algo "se supone simple".

Saludos

Comment: En que layout sucede según el LogCat? Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute. Agrega toolbar.xml por favor.

Comment: @Jorgesys Agregue el toolbar.xml, sobre lo del LogCat. Sinceramente, nunca lo he ocupado, pero deje el error que me da la aplicación.

Answer (score -1):

> Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

En la mayoría de los casos, este error es provocado porque en tu layout o vista usas la propiedad `android:layout_width`, **pero no agregas `android:layout_height`** o la propiedad esta mal escrita.

Comment: revise todas las vistas y a todos los elementos le he puesto layout_width y layout_height. Ahora bien, nose si mi menu.xml lo necesita. Ya que no tienen, pero cuando les agregue tampoco me funciono.

Comment: menu.xml no lo necesita, ya revisas el layout que carga el include, toolbar.xml?